# Synchronize SQLite With MySql by sending array of available quotes and receive the missing Android Java

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

Synchronize SQLite With MySql by sending array of ids for the quotes available in the SQLite to php script that will compare it with the available in the database and receive the missing quotes

this method will work in every moment when the app started

btw i know i have mistakes in the php script for that i'm asking now

im facing this error !

> D/error: org.json.JSONException: Value Arraynull of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

thank you !

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public Map<String,String> readIds(){

SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME_QUOTES,null);

Map<String,String> QuotesModuleArray = new HashMap<String, String>();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

    do {
        QuotesModuleArray.put("quote_id"+"["+cursor.getString(0)+"]", cursor.getString(0));

    }while (cursor.moveToNext());

}

cursor.close();

return QuotesModuleArray;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void Quotes_SQLITE() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

String url=".../android/checkquotes.php";

Map<String,String> arrayListQuotes;
dbHandler = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
arrayListQuotes = dbHandler.readIds();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new Map[]{arrayListQuotes}));

quotesListSQLite.clear();

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        response -> {


            Log.e("Quotesqlite : ",response.toString());


            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i++){
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    int quote_id = jsonObject.getInt("quote_id");
                    String quote_name = jsonObject.getString("quote_name");
                    String quote_details = jsonObject.getString("quote_details");
                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    String parent_id = jsonObject.getString("parent_id");
                    int language_id = jsonObject.getInt("language_id");


                    QuoteSQLite quote = new QuoteSQLite(quote_id , quote_name , quote_details , status,parent_id, language_id);

                    dbHandler.Add_Quote(quote_id,quote_name,quote_details, status,parent_id, language_id);

                    quotesListSQLite.add(quote);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("error",error.getMessage()+"");
        if((error.getMessage()+"").equals("null")) {
            try {
                Quotes_SQLITE();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
})
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

        Map<String, String> params;
        params=arrayListQuotes;

       
        return params;
    }
};

requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

  }
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'ibnabita_alihaydar');
define('DB_PASS', '81336874');
define('DB_NAME', 'ibnabita_secure_imam');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');


$allarray = array();
$toaddarray = array();
$flag = [];
$i = 0 ;
if(mysqli_connect_error($conn))
{
 echo "Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql="select quote_id from quotes";

$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result2)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
array_push($allarray,$row["quote_id"]);
}
}

$ids = array();

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
$ids[] = $_POST[$key];
}


 $data = json_decode($ids,true);

 foreach($data as $item) { //foreach element in $arr

 echo $item."\n" ;

 }


foreach($allarray as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
//echo $item."\n" ;

if(in_array( $item ,$data))
{


}
else
{
$sql23="select * from quotes where quote_id=".$item;
$result23=mysqli_query($conn,$sql23);
$row23=mysqli_fetch_array($result23,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$flag[]=$row23;

 }

 }
 print(json_encode($flag,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));



 mysqli_close($conn); 

 ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify `mistakes in the php script `. Do you receive errors, wrong output, something else? Please add as much detail as you can.

Comment: Unrelated but I've never seen a need for `array_push`, it is the same as `$allarray[] = $row["quote_id"];`.... additionally `$_POST[$key]` should be the same as `$value`.

Comment: D/error: org.json.JSONException: Value Arraynull of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Debug on the PHP side first, are you sending back JSON to the JAVA app? Please edit the question to include errors and details, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73517843/edit.